# I installed a newer version of git but homebrew doesn't recognize it

Tags: linux, terminal

So when I tried to install gcc using homebrew, it gave me an error message saying

```
Error: Command failed with exit 129: git
Error: 'curl' must be installed and in your PATH!
```

Then I checked the homebrew git version ( see attached) [image]

And when I typed

```
git --version
```

The system returns

```
git version 2.23.0
```

The directory to the newest git is also in the path. So I am really not sure what the problem is

Comment: Have you tried installing/upgrading `curl` and ensuring the most recent version is found first in `$PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

A strong possibility of your terminal and `$PATH` got confused. Either close terminal, or be super safe by logging out as your user and logging back in.

Comment: Related to this answer, I'd also use `which git` or `whereis git` to ensure which git executable is being launched.

Comment: I went back to the $PATH and eliminated all the directories that could potentially confuse the terminal. Its still not recognizing it. Also, which git returns the directory to the git that I want

Comment: Is `curl` in your `$PATH`? From the error message I would say not.